# Can <on-entry> inside decision state be called multiple times?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am new to Spring Webflow and I find that on-entry inside decision state is being called multiple times. Basically, a method call happens inside on-entry and I would like to know if there is a possibility that the decision state is called multiple times?

Comment: can you post the code for your flow?

Comment: Certainly a state can be visited multiple times, and each time `on-entry` will be executed.